# Can I modify Javadoc comments generated by maven-javadoc-plugin 2.10.4?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

When I build a maven project, using maven-javadoc-plugin 2.10.4, it generates the .java files with some Javadoc comments that look something like:

```
&lt;complexType>
  &lt;complexContent>
```

etc...

The problem is the doclint for Java 8 can't handle the ">" symbols that are produced by the plugin. If the plugin would output "& gt;" in place of the ">" this would be okay.

Strangely, the documentation shows output with "& gt;" in place of the ">". You can find this output here at Example 8: http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html:

But after searching for a long time I could find nothing in the documentation about how to get this output.

I don't want to just shut off doclint completely, so I excluded the packages these generated sources belong to, but if possible I'd prefer to not exclude them and find a way to get the output to work properly.

Comment: please let's clarify: 1. javadoc(-plugin) *does not* generate nor `.java` files nor javadoc within. 2. `jaxb2:xjc` (and already jaxb1) generates `.java` files with this defect... (can reproduce).

Comment: update: *cannot reproduce* with latest jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4.0 (...once running) ..it gives me: `&lt;/complexContent&gt; ... `

Comment: looks like [this issue](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/973) (resolved by jaxb.2.2.11)